# WPF - How to bind generic method in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, methods, bind

I have a class with a static method that returns a Dictionary.  The signature of the method is as follows:
`public static Dictionary<int, string> CodeLookup<T>() where T : EntityCodeBase`

At the moment, I'm using this method to bind to my comboboxes in the code behind, like so:
`this.cboState.ItemsSource = CodeCache.CodeLookup<StateCode>();`

Would someone please be able to point me in the correct direction for doing this in XAML so that I can remove this kind of stuff from my codebehind?

Thanks,
Sonny

Comment: This used to be one of my most wanted features. These days I use a ViewModel to expose the function as a read-only property.

Comment: @Jon, sometimes it's handy to do so, but I think it makes the View template too dependent on backend implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly binding to a particular method. You should create a property and bound that to it.

```
public Dictionary<int, string> Code {
    get { return CodeCache.CodeLookup<StateCode>(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you cannot do it for generic methods

[more info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37320/How-To-Bind-To-Generic-Method-In-XAML.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a property in my viewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Contact> AllContacts
    {
        get { return _applicationViewModel.CurrentContacts; }
    }
```

And here is my XAML:

```
<ListView Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllContacts}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Last Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="First Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Work Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=OfficePhone, Converter={StaticResource phoneConverter}}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Cell Phone" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CellPhone, Converter={StaticResource phoneConverter}}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Email Address" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=PrimaryEmail}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Just set the DataContext to the ViewModel and you get everything you need.  Check out MVVM pattern for more info.

There are ways to bind to a static method but if all you are doing is basic databinding then it's a bit of overkill.  Take a look at Actions if you are interested.